# What is needed and how much does it cost to get the tarjeta de la seguridad social in Spain?

Tags: eu-citizens, social-security, spain

1. When a Non-Spanish citizen (but from EU), who is *empadronado* (resident) in Spain, what does he/she need to do and to pay, if he/she wants a *tarjeta de la seguridad social* (social security card)?
2. Same questions for a Spanish citizen, who has been living abroad for some years.

And for children (age 8 and below)?

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer the question about Spanish citizens, but when I (UK citizen) obtained my social security card about 5 years ago it didn't cost me anything. Nor, for that matter, did registering for the *tarjeta sanitaria*. The only key piece of documentation which I had to pay for was the NIE.

Comment: I don't have official backups for saying this, but yes, AFAIK, if you have a valid NIE and the relative that's "in charge of you" is in good standing with *Seguridad Social*, your *Tarjeta Sanitaria* is granted. If you're out of your "Comunidad Autónoma" maybe you're denied some services, but not on your residence zone.